# SQL Server continuous job

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to run a job continuously which includes a stored procedure. This stored procedure does a critical task where it processes huge load of data as they come. As I know, it is not allowed to run 2 or more instances of a job in the same time by SQL Server it self. So, my questions are

1. Is there a way to run SQL Sever job continuously?
2. Do continuously running jobs hurt performance of the server?

Comment: You can schedule this job to run every 5 mintues or so. It doesn't make much sense when you can you want it to run "continuously"?

Comment: Why does it need to run continuosly? Is it because it needs to process new data when it arrives? Best way to handle such scenario is an asynchronous trigger. i.e. a trigger sends a message to a broker queue when new data arrives and then the receiver starts the processing (maybe wait a few seconds if data is added in batch). I have many such solution in production and it works very well.

Comment: @adrianm has a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

There are continuous replication jobs; however, those are continuous because of an inline switch used in the command line and not due to the job being scheduled as continuous.

The only way to emulate a continuous job is to simply have it run often. There is an option under scheduling to run the job down to every second 24/7/365. With that said, you will need to be careful that the job isn't overrunning itself and that it is efficient enough to not cause issues with your server.

Whether it will effect performance is going to be reliant on what it does. If the job only selects the current date/time (not a very useful thing to do but an example), I would not expect an issue; however, if it runs complicated algorithms then it almost certainly going to cause issues.

I would recommend running this on a test server before putting it into production.